# Что за новая кнопка "Поблагодарить за ответ" на EnSO?

Tags: обсуждение, ответы

На enSO около ответов появилась кнопочка

> Say **thanks** for this answer.

Что она делает? И это какой-то эксперимент или скоро у нас тоже будет?

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Просто новые кнопки с emoj [What do the plans for incorporating “new ways to say thanks” look like?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339283/348096) Пока обкатывают на Teams и en so.

Comment: [Saying thanks: testing a new Reactions feature](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/06/17/saying-thanks-testing-a-new-reactions-feature/)

Comment: Для полноты картины - ссылка на заминусованное обсуждение фичи - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398367/feature-test-thank-you-reaction

Comment: @Kromster ох, давненько мне пагинация в списке ответов не попадалась

Comment: Долой такие кнопки!

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica а чем вам не нравится? Вроде ничему не мешает.

Comment: @mymedia Меньше голосовать будут...

Comment: @mymedia дублирует существующий функционал (кнопку вверх и галку)

Comment: @Kromster, не дублирует.

Comment: @Qwertiy, дублирует, почём зря. Давайте тогда ещё добавим "мне нравится", "согласен", "+1", "вы правы", "кг/ам" ...

Comment: @Kromster чего скромничать, некоторые сервисы позволяют добавить вообще любой Emoji в качестве реакции 

Comment: @Kromster, вообще, гораздо лучше было бы с несколькими рейтингами.

Comment: @andreymal github e.g.

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica гитхаб фигня, у него всего 8 emoji на выбор 

Comment: @andreymal А вам 256 надо? Или сразу 4294967296 ;)